# .val() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

guys

this is my html part :

```html
<div class="radio">
 <input type="radio" name="certain" id="oui" value="oui"/>
 <label for="oui">
     oui
</label>
 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="certain" id="non" value="non" checked="checked"/>
 <label for="non">
     non
 </label>
</div>
```

```
var espece = $('#espece');
                var poil = $('#poil');
                var _certain = $('[name = "certain"]');
                var certain = null;

                _certain.each(function(index, element){
                    if(_certain[index].checked){
                        certain = element;
                    }
                });

                var continent_valeur = $('select option:selected').val();

                /* Test des champs */
                if(espece.val() == '' || poil.val() == '' || certain.val() == '' || continent_valeur == ""){
                    alert("Veuillez remplir tous les champs !");
                }
```

When i submit my form, i have an error on my var certain in the condition if. It says certain.val() is not a function.

But var certain contains the good value of my radio yes or not.

i don't understand can you help me please ?

Comment: `$('[name = "certain"]')` is `null` try removing the spaces `$('[name="certain"]')`

Comment: but `certain = element` after, `var certain = null`, now certain worth the object input no ?

Comment: Try 'certain.value' instead!

Comment: `$('[name = "certain"]')` is not null when I write `$('[name = "certain"]').val();`

Comment: or certain = $(element); in js line no.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use each, element represents a non-jquery node.
You just need to change

```
certain = element;
```

**to**

```
certain = $(element);
```

and you should be to go.

Any JQuery questions you may have can be found from W3Schools:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

and yours specifically:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/misc_each.asp

Answer (score 2):

`val()` is a [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) that is only applicable to jQuery objects and not valid for plain JavaScript elements.

If you want to use plain vanilla JS then you have to use `certain.value` or in case of jQuery you can use `$(certain).val()`.

Refer code:

```js
var espece = $('#espece');
var poil = $('#poil');
var _certain = $('[name = "certain"]');
var certain = null;

_certain.each(function(index, element) {
  if (_certain[index].checked) {
    certain = element;
  }
});

var continent_valeur = $('select option:selected').val();

/* Test des champs */
if (espece.val() == '' || poil.val() == '' || $(certain).val() == '' || continent_valeur == "") {
  alert("Veuillez remplir tous les champs !");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="certain" id="oui" value="oui" />
  <label for="oui">
     oui
</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="certain" id="non" value="non" checked="checked" />
  <label for="non">
     non
 </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this because the val function is to be applied over a jquery object, try this instead

```
$(element).val();
```

Also, in your each there's no need of doing **_certain[index].checked** since you already get the element in the second parameter of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate through a jQuery collection of elements with `.each`, it provides you with the index and *the element itself*. The second argument isn't a jQuery-wrapped element - it's the plain element.

Either use the ordinary Javascript method to get the value from the element:

```
`certain.value`
```

Or select it with jQuery first:

```
`$(certain).val()`
```